# Node keeps sending GET /sockjs-node/info requests after terminating with CTRL + C

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I don't think it has much to do with the issue, but I'm running a react app in development environment, after terminating (i think) the node process with `ctrl + c` , I keep getting these requests.

[image]

Any clues? Thank's in advance.

Comment: Did you find a good solution? PSKILL dotnet.exe is one way to do it, but then that'll only work if your'e not running any other dotnet.exe. Also I saw somewhere that using 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost can cause this more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its happens when you use socket in your application. When your server loads in the browser, your socket client establishes a connection between the socket client and socket.io on server side. When you stop node application (CTRL + C) you just stop the server side loop, while the client side loop try to connect/reconnect to server and you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your browser is trying to connect to Node and it gets connection refused errors, which seems reasonable if you stopped the server.

What did you expect to get when you stop your server?

Comment: free cookie dough

Comment: The same thing happens to me in my Vue app. Why would it try to connect to Node at all? I don't send any requests to the server.

Comment: @OranitDar Did you start your node in some developer mode where the browser is auto-refreshed once you edited something? Then most likely is that package that does the auto-refresh trying to reconnect to node.

Comment: @MartinC. Thanks! Truth is I can't remember, however the browser does auto refresh whenever I edit my code... if it happens only in developer mode than everything's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when I mistakenly added a loop between two required javascript / typescript resources.
On a resource "A", when the resource was loading, it was making a remote call to get a resource B.
When the resource B required something from A, a require/import was added and it ended up in a loop, what it was solved splitting the file A to extract the required constant to another file removing the loop.