# React - Infinite looping xhr sockjs-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have never hosted a website using react.js (Create-React-App).

I have made this website online but I have not turned on the API.

[image]

i don't know why i get auto looping xhr socketjs-nodes like this:

[image: Auto Looping]
[image]
and even though I only entered 1 project using React.js and got Physical Memory Usage almost 600MB is this all because of this xhr?

here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.12",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.6.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.7.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "forever": "^0.15.3",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-cookie": "^3.0.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.8.12",
    "react-images": "^0.5.19",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "react-select": "^2.3.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=40000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't help you, but if someone who knows React come to do so, he'll probably ask you for your code. I think you don't provide enough details to be helped.

Comment: I already update the question. I actually really confused how to explain this and give more details. i just dont know how can be this xhr is INFINITE Looping @Ctorres

Comment: We need your code, the part that is sending this request in order to help you.

Comment: i dont know which one is the part is sending this request because in localhost isnt @SergeK.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)'s requests (maybe [`hot module replacement`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) feature is enabled, not sure, maybe something else). Create-React-App uses it under the hood in development mode if I'm not mistaken (sorry, didn't use it a lot). So I believe it's fine, not sure if those 600MB of memory usage are related to it though.

**My personal sidenote:** I always found those bootstrap tools like Create-React-Apps a bad thing for beginners because it's hard to understand what's happening under the hood. My advice - either dig into what create-react-app uses under the hood to understand the stack better or just create your react app from scratch, it's not hard at all and IMO better. You'll probably just need `node` + `webpack` + `react`

Comment: So i need to change my React-app to server side rendering?

Comment: No, you can use client side rendering if you want. The point is you have these xhr requests most likely because of `webpack-dev-server`, which is totally fine since it's used for development environment only. Webpack-dev-server injects some js code in your bundle which makes those requests. When you switch to a production server you won't have those requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and in my case the error was in my code where there was a loop between two resources, in one a resource "B" was requested from a resource "A", and in "B" it requested "A" to obtain an element of it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68202789/2493852

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue with a production React.js app just today. When accessing the production React app, we were still seeing these errors, even though a production build is deployed.

Later only we got to know that some development artifacts slid into build artifacts during the build process. This had happened because the app was being built for production while a development server was running. While the app was being built, it had also taken the temporary development artifacts generated by the `webpack-dev-server` into account and had included those in the production bundle.

To make sure this doesn't happen again, we made sure not to production build React apps while the development server/s is/are running for the same app.